# hide/show php checkbox by id like www.anysite.php?id=10

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, hide, show

I have a form and a checkbox. By click on the checkbox, a div within some other divs will show up or hide. This works! But, if i visit my page with an id like xxxxx.php?id=10, the checkbox is checked but the divs are hide. if i click on the checkbox, the divs will show up, but the checkbox is unchecked (bad for e.g. mysql updates).. hope anyone can help me by this issue..

Here my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Show').hide();
  $("input[name=mycheckbox]").click(function () {
    $('#Show').toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="yes"> my option
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="Show">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textinput" class="control-label">Company </label>
      <div class="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My input field have this code (php doesn't work in the snippet):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="yes" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo $row->mycheckbox == "yes" ? 'checked="checked"' : "";}?>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `$("input[name=mycheckbox]").change(function () {
    $('#Show').toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use `change` event, trigger using [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on page load so that the `div` in sync with the state of checkbox element.

Also you should [`.toggle(display)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

```
$("input[name=mycheckbox]").change(function () {
   $('#Show').toggle(this.checked);
}).trigger('change');
```